# Starting an activity in a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to start an Activity from `onReceive()` method of `BroadcastReceiver`,but an  `ActivityNotFound` exception occurs every time. Please check and tell me what is wrong with my code

```
    <activity android:name="NearbyFriends"></activity>

    <receiver android:name="AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver"/>
```

and the code to call the other Activity is

```
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(); 
    Intent1.setClassName("com.android.letscatchupclientside","com.android.letscatchupclientside.NearbyFriends");
    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, NearbyFriends.class); 
intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<activity android:name="com.android.letscatchupclientside.NearbyFriends"></activity>
```

then

```
Intent(this, NearbyFriends.class);
```